# Error using a ternary operator

Tags: java, android

As shown in the following code, I would like to use ternary operator. But I am getting an error saying: "; expected" but I think, there is no need to add the semi-colon.

**Code**:

```
.filter(new Predicate<List<String>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(@NonNull List<String> strings) throws Exception {
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String string : strings) {
            Log.i(TAG, ".filter(): string: " + string);
            string.toLowerCase().startsWith("b") ? lst.add(string): continue;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, ".filter(): lsr: " + lst);
        return lst.size() > 0;
    }
})
```

Comment: Which line is the error on? ...

Comment: Ternary operation is used to assign or return values, continue is an instruction

Comment: The last two operands have to return a value of the same type (that is not `void`) . So obviously a void method or `continue` have really nothing to do in a ternary operator.

Comment: Why have `continue` as the very last statement in the loop. Kind of meaningless, you know.

Comment: @Andreas if you want to put the `continue;` instruction at the beginning you'll have to test the negation of the given assertion.

Comment: @мυѕτавєւмo I wasn't talking about the end of the ternary operator, I was talking about putting `continue` in the last statement of the loop block. Being the last statement, the loop *will* "continue" right there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operation is used to assign or return values, `continue;` is an instruction, to keep it simple use something like:

```
if(string.toLowerCase().startsWith("b")) {
    lst.add(string); 
} else {  
    continue;
}
```

Comment: if you add an explanation on WHY you can't use ternary operator here the answer is perfect

Comment: @user202729 just for clarification. stackoverflow doesn't make it easy for use to properly intend the code...

Comment: @PhilippSander That's [status-bydesign]. You're supposed to write the code in your editor and copy here. As an extra bonus, OP can be sure that the code works as expected, and contains no typo.

Comment: @user202729 sorry I have no IDE available to indent it.

Comment: In this case you can drop the `else` clause entirely.

Comment: @user202729 No, I don't

Comment: @user202729, are you here to help? Then chill. If you don't like the indentation, help the guy out, edit it as you wish, instead of complaining

Comment: but i also tried                             string.toLowerCase().startsWith("b")? lst.add(string) : lst.add(" ");

Comment: @LetsamrIt But even `string.toLowerCase().startsWith("b")? lst.add(string) : lst.add(" ");` doesn't work, because the `?:` conditional operator is exactly that: An *operator*, i.e. part of an *expression*, and is not a valid Java *statement*. Similarly, you can't just write `2 + 7;`, which is also just an expression, and not a statement. Only some expressions are also valid as statements. See [14.8. Expression Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) in the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot use `continue` in a ternary condition, since `continue` is a statement, not an expression, as what the ternary condition is expecting. More on the expression statements [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) (credits to [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas))

My suggestion instead of trying to try making use of the ternary condition, is to use java streams, since you are already using `filter` and predicates:

```
.filter(strings -> strings.stream()
                          .anyMatch(string -> string.toLowerCase().startsWith("b")));
```

This will have the same result you are trying to do with collecting the strings that start with `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The Conditional Operator `? :` is an *expression*, not a *statement* (see [JLS 15.25. Conditional Operator `? :`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)).

Expressions cannot be written as statement, i.e. the following are both invalid:

```
2 + 7;
a == 42 ? foo() : bar();
```

Note that only some expressions are also valid as statements, and `? :` is not one of them ([JLS 14.8. Expression Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)):

> ```
> ExpressionStatement:
>   StatementExpression ;
>
> StatementExpression:
>   Assignment
>   PreIncrementExpression
>   PreDecrementExpression
>   PostIncrementExpression
>   PostDecrementExpression
>   MethodInvocation
>   ClassInstanceCreationExpression
> ```

In addition, the [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) of the Conditional Operator is:

> ```
> ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : ConditionalExpression
> ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : LambdaExpression
> ```

Meaning that all 3 parts must be *expressions*, and `continue` is a statement, not an expression.

To summarize, `? :` is an expression and cannot be used as a statement, and it can only contain expressions, not statements. It is not a replacement for the `if` statement.

So, your code should be written using `if` statement:

```
for (String string : strings) {
    Log.i(TAG, ".filter(): string: " + string);
    if (string.toLowerCase().startsWith("b")) {
        lst.add(string);
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Of course, having a `continue` statement at the end of the loop is redundant (the loop *will* continue anyway), so the `else` can be removed:

```
for (String string : strings) {
    Log.i(TAG, ".filter(): string: " + string);
    if (string.toLowerCase().startsWith("b"))
        lst.add(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Ternary operation is used to assign or return values, continue is an instruction.

```
string.toLowerCase().startsWith("b") ? lst.add(string): continue;
```

Replace this line by

```
if(string.toLowerCase().startsWith("b"))
     lst.add(string);
else
     continue;
```